# VBA loop copy paste one column multiple times together with columns in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a loop in VBA Excel which copy and paste first column from Pivot table as many times as the number of all the columns in this Pivot table (if I have 62 columns I need to copy paste the first column 61 times in one column in another sheet2). I need to copy the other 61 columns into one column together with the header of each column in third column in sheet2.

```
Sub SelCopCol()
    Dim ss As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NC As Long
      
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets(sheet1_Pivot)
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(sheet2)
        
        'Define the range of rows 
    ss = ws1.Range("A:A").Find("Grand Total", ws1.Cells(1, 1)).Row
    NC = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     For i = 2 To NC
            ws2.Range("C2:C" & ss - 1) = ws1.Range("A2:A" & ss - 1).Value
            ws2.Range("H2:H" & ss - 1) = ws1.Range("B2:B" & ss - 1).Value 
            ws2.Range("M2:M" & ss - 1) = ws1.Range("B1").Value
'I should use a variables for "B2:B" and "B1" but I couldn't 
      Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add an input and expected output?

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't find how to upload excel file. Could you please advise?

Comment: @you can create some tables copy-pasting your data. Or some screenshots. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```vb
Sub SelCopCol()
    
    Dim ss As Long '<< not string
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim numRows As Long, NC As Long, rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rngDest As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("sheet1_Pivot")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("sheet2")
        
    NC = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ss = ws1.Range("A:A").Find("Grand Total", ws1.Cells(1, 1)).Row
    
    Set rng = ws1.Range("A2:A" & ss - 1)          'row labels
    numRows = rng.Rows.Count
    Set rng2 = rng.Offset(0, 1)                  'first data column
    Set rngDest = ws2.Range("C2").Resize(numRows) 'first "paste" destination
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While rng2.Column <= NC     'until we reach the last column
        'copy values
        rngDest.Value = rng.Value
        rngDest.EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = rng2.Value
        rngDest.EntireRow.Columns("M").Value = ws1.Cells(1, rng2.Column).Value
        
        Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(0, 1)          'one column over
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(numRows) 'move destination range down
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```